# Multilevel filter

Tags: views

I would like to make a form where users can choose categories to get to a node. 
For example they choose a magazines category (science, drupal, mechanics ....) and then publication year and then publication months.

Is it possible to do this with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) or [Views Dynamic Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dynamic_fields) but allow users to choose let's say Drupal category in magazines and then get a list of publication years available for this category only?

Answer (score 0):

See [this long discussion](https://www.drupal.org/node/1197752) on a similar situation - there are a number of options available depending on your specific needs, including the module [Views Dependant Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters). Here is an excerpt from the project page of this module:

> Allows the presence of exposed filters on a view to be controlled by values in another exposed filter. Dependent filters are hidden when not relevant, and their values are not considered when the exposed form is submitted.

The module is compatible with both the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) basic and the [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) form plugins.